# Component ojCollapsible is not found

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

i am using require.js and knockout.js and creating a small menu navigation using accordion and collaspable components.

the index.html has tag

```
 <div id="navigationContent" data-bind="ojModule: { name: 'navContent'}"></div>
```

the navContent.tmpl.html has

```
<div id="navContent" data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojAccordion'}">
  <div id="c1">
    <span><</span> Usage</span>
    <p class="oj-p">Users</p>
  </div>
  <div id="c3" data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojCollapsible', expanded:true}">
    <span>Diagnostics</span>
    <div>
     <p class="oj-p">Errors</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the navContent.js

```
require(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout', 'jquery', 'ojs/ojknockout', 'ojs/ojaccordion', 'ojs/ojcollapsible'],
function(oj, ko, $)
{
  $(document).ready(
    function()
    {
      ko.applyBindings(null, document.getElementById('navContent'))
    }
  );
});
```

however, on running the page the menu doesnt appear. the javascript console shows error:

```
Component ojCollapsible is not foundc.u.Wv @ ojcore.js:13c.u.error @ ojcore.js:12a.ia.XS @ ojknockout.js:16a.ia.Qj @ ojknockout.js:12function.a.j.q @ knockout-3.3.0.js:66l @ knockout-3.3.0.js:44a.w.a.j @ knockout-3.3.0.js:47(anonymous function) @ knockout-3.3.0.js:66a.a.o @ knockout-3.3.0.js:10g @ knockout-3.3.0.js:65h @ knockout-3.3.0.js:63k @ knockout-3.3.0.js:63a.Ja @ knockout-3.3.0.js:69a.ia._init @ ojknockout.js:12(anonymous function) @ knockout-3.3.0.js:65a.Z.a.k.u @ knockout-3.3.0.js:35(anonymous function) @ knockout-3.3.0.js:65a.a.o @ knockout-3.3.0.js:10g @ knockout-3.3.0.js:65h @ knockout-3.3.0.js:63a.ub @ knockout-3.3.0.js:69(anonymous function) @ ojmodule.js:13
ojcore.js:13 Component ojAccordion is not found
```

I can see these are there in the lib folder where other components are. so not sure what is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is [OracleJET](http://jet.us.oracle.com/2.0.0/uiComponents-accordion-basicAccordion.html) code all of the ojs/xxxx components should already be registered for you.  But if you're using this code in the context of the JET QuickStart (i.e. --template=basic), then the ojModule data-bind in index.html is expecting you to use a Require.js `define()` block and return a viewModel function, as opposed to using the standalone `require()` blocks shown in the JET Cookbook.

I just got this code to work for navContent.js in QuickStart (nice job btw changing the QuickStart's ojModule data-bind from `viewName:` to `name:` in index.html...i missed that at first):

**navContent.js**

```
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout', 'jquery', 'ojs/ojknockout', 'ojs/ojaccordion', 'ojs/ojcollapsible'],
function(oj, ko, $)
{
  function navContentViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        console.log('navContentViewModel here...doesn\'t do much other than load the ojs/xxxx dependencies');
    }
    return navContentViewModel;
});
```